# How to get variable from object to another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, properties

```
var options = {
    properties: 'someValue'
};

var moved = {
    init:function() {
        console.log(properties) // get propeties from options object
    }
};
```

How to use options object properties in moved object?

Answer (score 2):

The property is obtained through its object:

```
console.log( options.properties );
```

Comment: @IamAndy Can you consider accepting please? It helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the options object

```
var moved = {
    init:function() {
        console.log(options.properties) // get propeties from options object
    }
};
```